# Commission on smart contract execution (cut on amount transfered)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

I'm sorry if it's the wrong place but I was asking my self where in the smart contracts websites like PancakeSwap or UniSwap takes their cut (0.2 and 0.3% if I'm right).

Willing to work with solidity and I didnt know if they just take their cut with a quick math and send it to their wallet or if there are other ways to do so.

Thanks for you answers !